# Amazon S3 and running PHP using an external server

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I know you can't run PHP on Amazon S3, but is there a way to host a static site on S3 and then have a contact form that runs using PHP from another server? In essence, I'm asking if the PHP file needs to be on S3 for it to run properly?

Comment: yes, or you could run php on ec2. the php file has to be on the server with php running, but a form(html page) with out php could be on s3 and point to another server

Answer (score 1):

No, the PHP file does not have to be on S3. Just put it on the other server and refer to the absolute (full) URL.

- Pages can submit forms to other domains (*e.g.* to the PHP server). This is actually what makes [CSRF](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) possible even when a server requires POST requests.
- Pages can load images, scripts, and stylesheets from other domains. In fact, it is very common for these assets to be loaded from separate servers or even third-party [content delivery networks](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). For example, Stack Overflow loads its copy of jQuery from `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js`.